# props not being passed properly - reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have two components, one of which is used for filling out a form, the other is for displaying the input once it is submitted. However, it currently only displays the input until the form is submitted, and then it goes away. What is happening to the state of the parent component when the form is submitted?

```
class Form extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      equation: null
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.mySubmitHandler}>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="equation"
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          />
        </form>
        <Parser value={this.state.equation}/>
      </div>
    );
  }

  handleInputChange = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  };

  mySubmitHandler = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ equation: event.target.value });
    alert("You are submitting " + this.state.equation);
    console.log(this.state.equation);
  };
}

class Parser extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.value}</div>;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is the `event.target.value` from the `form submit` event.
Since the event is coming from form submit, the target element is form and there is no `value` in the `target` element.
Update the component like below will solve your problem.

```
import React, {Component } from 'react';
export default class Hello extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      equation: null
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.mySubmitHandler}>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="equation"
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <Parser value={this.state.equation}/>
      </div>
    );
  }

  handleInputChange = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  };

  mySubmitHandler = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("You are submitting " + this.state.equation);
    console.log(this.state.equation);
  };
}

class Parser extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.value}</div>;
  }
}
```

Check the stackblitz solution.[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gqhvzs)

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using `this.setState({equation: event.target.value});` in mySubmitHandler.

The event.target for submit is the form itself and it has no value.
Therefore it sets equation to undefined.

The reason you see the correct state when you `console.log()` it is because setState is async and the state in that function call still has the old value with it.

Remove it and see if it works.

Comment: Didn't fix it, doesn't render the text while it's being typed anymore, but after submitting it still doesn't display.

Comment: You don't need e.preventDefault() in your handleInputChange. I am ont sure if that will help or not but, it's definitely not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I modified the `handleInputChange` and `mySubmitHandler` you use this

```
  handleInputChange = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      equation: event.target.value
    });
  };

mySubmitHandler = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("You are submitting " + this.state.equation);
    console.log(this.state.equation);
  };
```

Comment: there is no need for submit button inside form `unless` you need it. Enter key will submit the form automatically.

Comment: Ya correct , so i update the solution which is actually needed. Thanks.

Comment: there is noting wrong with the handleinput function, its working as expected. Issues is only in the submitHandler function. you can check my solution and stackblitz link.

Answer (score 0):

In `mySubmitHandler`, `event.target.value` is undefined, which is why the Parser text is disappearing. If you need to use `equation` in the submit handler, just use `this.state.equation` because it is has already been set via `handleInputChange`

```
mySubmitHandler = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    // event.target.value is undefined
    // this.state.equation has already been set via this.handleInputChange
    this.setState({ equation: event.target.value });
    alert("You are submitting " + this.state.equation);
    console.log(this.state.equation);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain two states equation and inputequation.

Now when you change input setstate inputequation. When you submit setstate equation to inputequation.

And one more thing

```
<input value={this.state.inputequation}/>
```

input should be controlled via your state.

Comment: currently the problem is because the input is not controlled component. So when the submit button is pressed the default behaviour of forms errasing happens. When input is controlled even after submitting your input will still have value of the state.

Comment: not exactly, currently the problem is, he is setting value inside form submit event, the value is `undefined` here and `onSubmit`  undefined is set to state. this is causing the value to go empty. You can check here the solution ```https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gqhvzs```

Answer (score 0):

You should check this [stackblitz](https://react-tjktyl.stackblitz.io) solution

I have used your code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Form extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      equation: null
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.mySubmitHandler}>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="equation"
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          />
        </form>
        <Parser value={this.state.equation}/>
      </div>
    );
  }

  handleInputChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  };

  mySubmitHandler = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("You are submitting " + this.state.equation);
  };
}


class Parser extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.value}</div>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix. You are accessing the incorrect property of the form.

```
this.setState({ equation: event.target.value });
```

This needs to be the name of the form element which is `equation`:

```
this.setState({ equation: event.target.equation.value });
```

Your updated handler:

```
  mySubmitHandler = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ equation: event.target.equation.value });
  };
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/80gwvfhd/12/)**